# How to use nested queries to do matrix power in sql?

Tags: sql, subquery

I just started learning sql and am currently working on matrix multiplication. I'm having trouble figuring out how to use nested query as a result to do matrix power. (e.g. like A^3)
Should I put the subquery in the FROM clause or WHERE clause?
Below is my attempt and I get syntax error near "(" on sqlite which isn't very helpful

```
SELECT A.i, A.j, SUM(A.val * A.val) AS val
FROM A, (SELECT A.i, A.j SUM(A.val * A.val) AS val
        FROM A
        WHERE A.i = A.i
        GROUP BY A.i, A.j) AS B
WHERE A.i = B.j 
GROUP BY A.i, B.j
```

Comment: This isn't an answer to the broader question, but for syntax error, I think you're missing a comma on second line `A.j SUM(A.val * A.val)` should be `A.j, SUM(A.val * A.val)`. The `WHERE A.i = A.i` also seems a little strange.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication would look like this in SQL:

```
select a.i, a.j,
       (select sum(rows.val * cols.val)
        from a rows cross join
             a cols
        where rows.i = a.i and
              cols.j = a.j and
              rows.j = cols.i
       ) as val
from a;
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use subquery for A^2? For A * B I use 
SELECT A.i, B.j, SUM(A.val * B.val) AS val
FROM A, B
WHERE A.j = B.i
GROUP BY A.i, B.j;
And I still don't know how to do A^3

Comment: @Han . . . No, but it is simpler in my opinion to do this using a subquery.  For greater powers, you would just repeat the multiplication logic.  Nothing requires that the `a` references in the subquery be the same table as the `a` in the outer query.